# How do I count occurrence of duplicate items in array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I would like to count the occurrence of each duplicate item in an array and end up with an array of only unique/non duplicate items with their respective occurrences.

Here is my code; BUT I don't where am going wrong!

```
<?php
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);

//$previous[value][Occurrence]

for($arr = 0; $arr < count($array); $arr++){

    $current = $array[$arr];
    for($n = 0; $n < count($previous); $n++){
        if($current != $previous[$n][0]){// 12 is not 43 -----> TRUE
            if($current != $previous[count($previous)][0]){
                $previous[$n++][0] = $current;
                $previous[$n++][1] = $counter++;
            }
        }else{  
            $previous[$n][1] = $counter++;
            unset($previous[count($previous)-1][0]);
            unset($previous[count($previous)-1][1]);
        }   
    }
}
//EXPECTED VALUES
echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($previous).'<br><br>';// 7
print_r($previous);// array( {12,1} , {21,2} , {43,6} , {66,1} , {56,1} , {78,2} , {100,1})
?>
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

[`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), enjoy :-)

```php
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'<br><br>';
print_r($vals);
```

Result:

```
No. of NON Duplicate Items: 7
Array
(
    [12] => 1
    [43] => 6
    [66] => 1
    [21] => 2
    [56] => 1
    [78] => 2
    [100] => 1
)
```

Comment: then array_keys($array) to get the desired output array;  PS you all need to work on your variable naming

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works on integers and strings. If you have an array of arrays or objects you will need to iterate through your array yourself, counting duplicates.

Answer (score 12):

if you want to try without `'array_count_values'`
you can do with a smart way here

```
<?php
$input= array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);

$count_values = array();
foreach ($input as $a) {

     @$count_values[$a]++;

}
echo 'Duplicates count: '.count($count_values);
print_r($count_values);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Sam T. I like your method how to you done in smart way. Can you please explain me @$count_values[$a]++;
what @ represent and what it does, Thanks your

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda it just suppresses the warnings.

Comment: Error suppressors give code an immediate smell.  I advise that developers avoid this technique as much as possible and instead handle notices and warnings properly.  I would never deem this to be "the smart way".

Answer (score 9):

Simplest solution (that's where PHP rocks) - **ONLY duplicates**:

```
$r = array_filter(array_count_values($array), function($v) { return $v > 1; });
```

and check:

```
print_r($r);
```

Result `$r`:

```
[43] => 6
[21] => 2
[78] => 2
```

Comment: array_filter(array_count_values($array), fn($v) => $v > 1 ); For extra pleasure :)

Comment: This is not only duplicates, but also triplicates and so on, i.e. multiplicates.

Comment: @ÖmerAn Yes, I treated the "duplicates" term here as all records which are more than 1, hence the "> 1" condition. Modify it according to you needs (e.g. "=== 2") if you want a specific number of occurences.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a multi-dimensional array you can use on PHP 5.5+ this:

```
array_count_values(array_column($array, 'key'))
```

which returns e.g.

```
 [
   'keyA' => 4,
   'keyB' => 2,
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a function recently that would check for a substring within an array that will come in handy in this situation.

```
function strInArray($haystack, $needle) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        $result = stripos($value,$needle);
        if ($result !== FALSE) return TRUE;
        $i++;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if (strInArray($array,$array[$i])) {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: This answer does not resolve the asked question.  This is, at best, the correct answer to a different question. https://3v4l.org/XqgDA

Answer (score 2):

You can also use it with text items array, u will get number of duplicates properly, but PHP shows

> Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER
>   values!

```
$domains = 
array (
  0 => 'i1.wp.com',
  1 => 'i1.wp.com',
  2 => 'i2.wp.com',
  3 => 'i0.wp.com',
  4 => 'i2.wp.com',
  5 => 'i2.wp.com',
  6 => 'i0.wp.com',
  7 => 'i2.wp.com',
  8 => 'i0.wp.com',
  9 => 'i0.wp.com' );

$tmp = array_count_values($domains);
print_r ($tmp);

    array (
      'i1.wp.com' => 2730,
      'i2.wp.com' => 2861,
      'i0.wp.com' => 2807
    )
```

Comment: PHP does not generate the Warning that you have described. https://3v4l.org/G7FvC

Answer (score 2):

> > Count duplicate element of an array in PHP without using in-built
> >     function

```
$arraychars=array("or","red","yellow","green","red","yellow","yellow");
$arrCount=array();
        for($i=0;$i<$arrlength-1;$i++)
        {
          $key=$arraychars[$i];
          if($arrCount[$key]>=1)
            {
              $arrCount[$key]++;
            } else{
              $arrCount[$key]=1;
        }
        echo $arraychars[$i]."<br>";
     }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arrCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a magical function PHP is offering to you it called [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Using parts of your code we will modify the loop as follows:

```
<?php
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);
$arr2 = array();
$counter = 0;
for($arr = 0; $arr < count($array); $arr++){
    if (in_array($array[$arr], $arr2)) {
        ++$counter;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        $arr2[] = $array[$arr];
    }
}
echo 'number of duplicates: '.$counter;
print_r($arr2);
?>
```

The above code snippet will return the number total number of repeated items i.e. *form the sample array* 43 is repeated 5 times, 78 is repeated 1 time and 21 is repeated 1 time, then it returns an array without repeat.

Comment: Dear researchers, using iterated calls of `in_array()` is one of worst options for this task in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

I came here from google looking for a way to count the occurrence of duplicate items in an array. Here is the way to do it simply:

```
$colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "blue"];

$unique_colors = array_unique($colors);                // ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
$duplicates = count($colors) - count($unique_colors);  // 6 - 4 = 2

if ($duplicates == 0) {
    echo "There are no duplicates";
}
echo "No. of Duplicates: " . $duplicates;

// Output: No. of Duplicates are: 2
```

**How array_unique() works?**

It elements all the duplicates.
**ex:**
Lets say we have an array as follows -

`$cars = array( [0]=>"lambo", [1]=>"ferrari", [2]=>"Lotus", [3]=>"ferrari", [4]=>"Bugatti");`

When you do `$cars = array_unique($cars);`
cars will have only following elements.
`$cars = array( [0]=>"lambo", [1]=>"ferrari", [2]=>"Lotus", [4]=>"Bugatti");`

To read more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using foreach loop. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aGPqe))

```
$array = array(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,4,5,6,88);
$set_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $set_array[$value]++;
}
print_r($set_array);
```

Output:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 1 in /in/aGPqe on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key 2 in /in/aGPqe on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key 3 in /in/aGPqe on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key 4 in /in/aGPqe on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key 5 in /in/aGPqe on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key 6 in /in/aGPqe on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key 88 in /in/aGPqe on line 6
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [88] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**this code will return duplicate value in same array**

```
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);
foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
  if(array_count_values($arr)[$item] > 1){
     echo "Found Matched value : ".$item." <br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Um, what? https://3v4l.org/C3dLj  Did you test this before posting?  Why would you ask PHP to perform the same function execution on the same re-encountered value in `$array`?

Answer (score -1):

```
$search_string = 4;
$original_array = [1,2,1,3,2,4,4,4,4,4,10];
$step1 = implode(",", $original_array); // convert original_array to string
$step2 = explode($search_string, $step1); // break step1 string into a new array using the search string as delimiter
$result = count($step2)-1; // count the number of elements in the resulting array, minus the first empty element
print_r($result); // result is 5
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    $input = [1,2,1,3,2,4,10];
    //if give string
    //$input = "hello hello how are you how hello";
    //$array = explode(' ',$input);
    $count_val = [];
    foreach($array as $val){
      $count_val[$val]++;
    }
    print_r($count_val);
//output ( [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [10] => 1 )
```