# extract duplicates and how many times they occur in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am developing a user driven eCommerce website and need some help. What I have is a function that will loop through an array remove duplicates and how many times they occur. I then need to run a function on each of those extracted duplicates as many times as they occur. The code I have so far works, but breaks when there are multiple duplicates with the same repetition count. Here is the code I have made so far..

```
$affiliates = array(11,11,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,14,14); //breaks the code
$affiliates = array(11,11,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,12,12,12,12,12); // works fine

$array = array();
$match_count = array();

  foreach($affiliates as $key => $affiliate) {
      $array[] = $affiliate;
  }

  arsort($array); // keeps array index in order

  foreach($array as $arrays) {
      if(array_value_count($arrays,$array) > 1) {   
          $match_count[] = array_value_count($arrays,$array);
      }
  }

  $match_count = array_unique($match_count);

  $array_unique = arrayDuplicate($array);

  $final_array = array_combine($match_count,$array_unique);

  foreach($final_array as $key => $value) {
      for($i = 0; $i < $key; $i++) {
          echo 'addOrder(affiliate_id = ' . $value . ') . '<br>';   
      }
  }
```

the functions

```
  function unique_array($array) {
       return array_unique($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
  }

  function arrayDuplicate($array) {
       return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array,array_unique($array)));
  }

  function array_value_count($match, $array) {
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value == $match)
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return $count;
  }
```

to fix the duplicates breaking the code I have tried this

```
 if(count($array_unique) - count($match_count_unique) == 1 ) // do something
```

or

```
if(count($array_unique) != count($match_count_unique) == 1 ) // do something
```

How would I know where to add the missing duplicate value count and array items correctly without them getting out of sync? OR Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [How do I count occurrence of duplicate items in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633954/how-do-i-count-occurrence-of-duplicate-items-in-array)

```
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'<br><br>';
print_r($vals);
```

Result

```
No. of NON Duplicate Items: 7

Array
(
[12] => 1
[43] => 6
[66] => 1
[21] => 2
[56] => 1
[78] => 2
[100] => 1
)
```

Duplicate items = (Array Size) - (Total Number of Unique Values)

Comment: I swear I tried this function!! So I guess I wrote all that code for nothing because it was already a native function!!!! In your opinion which will perform better for large arrays?

Comment: @handmdmr `array_count_values` does the exact same thing as the `foreach` loop in my solution. I don't either one will be more efficient since they basically literally do the same thing. @KanishkaGanguly  +1 for the built-in function, though @handmdmr you'll still need to loop through the results as i have shown, since you wanted to do something for each duped item

Comment: AFAIK, in-built functions are usually more optimized than what we could write ourselves.

Comment: using `array_count_values()` I will just then loop through them using the value for the iterator count and the key to reference the affiliate_id for the order. @CrayonViolet Answered your question but forgot to notify you, the explanation is below your code. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$affiliates = array(11,11,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,14,14); 

// get an array whose keys are the aff# and 
//the values are how many times they occur
$dupes = array();
foreach ($affiliates as $aff) {
  $dupes[$aff]++;
}
// remove the 1's since those aren't dupes
$dupes = preg_grep('~^1$~',$dupes,PREG_GREP_INVERT); 

// de-dupe the original array
$affiliates = array_unique($affiliates);

// for each duped affiliate...
foreach ($dupes as $aff => $affCount) {
  // for each time it was duped.. 
  for ($c=0;$c<$affCount;$c++) {
    // do something. $aff is the aff# like 11
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this will work, but i cannot check it till this evening. Straight and to the point, Instead of removing the number 1's I will store them in another variable, because those items still need to be ran through the `addOrder()` function.

Comment: @handmdmr okay i'm kind of curious.. if you have to run all the dupes and even the non-dupes through your `addOrder()` function.. why the need for separating them at all, vs. just looping through the original array?

Comment: I am designing a user driven eCommerce website. Every product uploaded to the db has a unique affiliate id. If a customer purchases multiple products on a single order, there is the possibility that those products are owned by multiple users. I need to be able to create separate orders for each affiliate.

Comment: So for example the array above would have five orders, 1 order for affiliate #11 with 2 of there products, 1 order for affiliate #12 with two of there products, affiliate #13 has an order with 3 products and affiliate #14 has order with 4 products. Then I need to make a master order for the admin to track all sales. It is probably unlikely that products would be purchased in this quantity on one order, but it's possible so i need to plan for it.