# How do I get sum of distinct value from php list that was exploded?

Tags: php

I have a list that is created from a mysql field that is exploded into a list

```
$calls=mysql_query("SELECT callback_info FROM  table WHERE callback_info !=''",$conn);

while($cust=mysql_fetch_array($calls)){

list($name,$time) = explode(",", $cust['callback_info']);
    echo $name."<br>";

}
```

This gives me something like:

```
Snoop
Daz
Kurupt
Snoop
Snoop
```

I want to show the distinct name with the number of times it appeared like:

```
Snoop (3)
Daz (1)
Kurupt (1)
```

How would I go about doing this?

UPDATE this worked for me... $name needed to be put into an array

```
$calls=mysql_query("SELECT callback_info FROM  table WHERE callback_info !=''",$conn);

$data = array();

while($cust=mysql_fetch_array($calls)){

    list($name,$time) = explode(",", $cust['callback_info']);
       $data[] = $emp;

    }

$array = array_count_values($data);

for ($i = 0; $i <  count($array); $i++) {
    $name=key($array);
    $number_calls=$array[$name];
    if ($number_calls<> ' ') {
       echo $name ." made ".  $number_calls ." calls<br> ";
       }
     next($array);
    }
```

Comment: Check this out: [Previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13633990/4637793). You can then use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: use `array_count_values`

Comment: thanks for the response, but that doesn't work

Comment: simply saying "doesn't work " will not help us help you