# how to get the values and keys with number of repetition from multidimensional array

Tags: arraylist

I have a multidimensional array in PHP and there is repetition in id, how can I get the number of repetition and the name?

```
$myArray['names'] = array(
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"13" , "name"=>"Omar"),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"13" , "name"=>"Omar"),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"13" , "name"=>"Omar"),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" )
);
```

I want to make it look like this array 
    **in need it to be**

```
$array = ("id"=>"12", "name"=>"ahmed", "Count"=>"5")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count occurrence of duplicate items in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633954/how-do-i-count-occurrence-of-duplicate-items-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foreach` loop get his done as shown below:

```
$myArray['names'] = array(
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"13" , "name"=>"Omar"),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"13" , "name"=>"Omar"),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"13" , "name"=>"Omar"),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" ),
    array( "id"=>"12", "name"=>"Ahmed" )
);

$remove_duplication = array();
$key_exist = array();
foreach( $myArray as $row ) {
    foreach ( $row as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $item["id"], $key_exist ) ) {
            $remove_duplication[$item["id"]]["Count"] = $remove_duplication[$item["id"]]["Count"] + 1;
        } else {
            $key_exist[] = $item["id"];
            $remove_duplication[$item["id"]] = $item;
            $remove_duplication[$item["id"]]["Count"] = 1;
        }

    }
}
print'Removed Duplication: <pre>';
print_r($remove_duplication);
print'</pre>';

$rearrange_array = array();
foreach ( $remove_duplication as $key => $value ) {
  $rearrange_array[] = $value;
}
print'Arrange array with 0: <pre>';
print_r($rearrange_array);
print'</pre>';
```

Comment: but it gives me an array not begin with 0

Comment: @ahmedalthalgy Check now