# How to PROPERLY store duplicate keys of array

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, count, store

`$statues` is an array of multiple objects from a twitter api response.

`$status->retweeted_status->user->screen_name` is the username of a Twitter account.

`$status->retweeted_status->user->profile_image_url_https` is the image from that user.

What I want is:

1. Store username
2. Store image URL
3. COUNT **how many times does this user repeats**.

As I know, is not possible to have repeated keys into asocciative array, So i wrote down this code:

```
$vector = [];

foreach($statuses as $status ){
      
        if(array_key_exists ( $status->retweeted_status->user->screen_name ,$vector)){
            $vector[$status->retweeted_status->user->screen_name]['cont'] = $vector[$status->retweeted_status->user->screen_name]['cont'] + 1;
        
        } else{
            $vector[$status->retweeted_status->user->screen_name] = array(
                'img' => str_replace('_normal','_400x400',$status->retweeted_status->user->profile_image_url_https),
                'cont' => 1
            );
        }
      


    }
```

The result is the following:
[image]

That's okay, but I want to know:

1. Is there a better way to Store username, image, and also count how many times does this user appears (Optimize my code)?
2. How can I order the array to show FIRST the user with most repetitions and last the user with less (Descendent) ?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the User I think what you're looking for is here: [Count occurrence of duplicate items in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633954/how-do-i-count-occurrence-of-duplicate-items-in-array)

Basically use `array_count_values`. There's other built in array functions that will order your array for you if needed.